# Disable print and export functionality for a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server

How do I disable print and export functionality for a SharePoint site? A site owner has requested me to do so...

Answer (score 0):

Print can be disabled using css:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    body {display:none;visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

Export a site is something done in Central Administration where users should't have access to.